# Img dynamic scale into box-height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to build a website with the same features as seen on http://www.babingtonhouse.co.uk/house The boxes have to be always same height and the images should proportualy scale within the box-height. How can i do that? Unfortunaltey i cannot find the js-code to lear how they did it.

I've tried it with css (img-class: width:100%) but on some sizes the ing will be height than the text-box.

Thanks for any help.

best regards
thomas

Comment: We could use some code answering your question.

Comment: an where can i see it

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this

http://jsfiddle.net/2jrn208p/1/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="image" id="img1"></div>
    <div class="image" id="img2"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrap {
    height:90vh
}
.image {

    height:50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
#img1 {
    background-image: url('http://i56.tinypic.com/2hr0twi.jpg');
}
#img2 {
    background-image: url('http://media.desura.com/images/members/1/420/419240/SERB_VILLAGE.jpg');
}
```